# Python. Наследование классов. Нужен ли __init__

Tags: python, классы, наследование, методы, атрибуты

Вне зависимости от того, где я присваиваю значение переменной (во 2 строке или в 5) строка 29 работает. Но только до тех пор, пока я не закомментирую строку 16, тогда выдаётся ошибка:

AttributeError: 'Fish' object has no attribute 'b'

Опять же вне зависимости от того в **init** функции присваиваивается значение переменной или до неё.

Исходя из этого 2 вопроса:

Первый: Почему строка 16 влияет на правильность работы?

Второй: Зачем внутри класса нужно "def **init**(self):", если и без него всё работает

Пример кода текстом:

```
class Animal:
  a = 7                      # it doesn't metter where "a = 7" at line 2
  def __init__(self):
    self.num_eyes = 2
    self.a = 7              # or 5, line 29 works, until line 16 doesn't com.

  def breathe(self):
    self.b = self.a + 1
    print("Inhale, exhale.")

class Fish(Animal):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def breathe(self):
    #super().breathe()        # if this com. line 29 doesn't work
    print("under water.")
    
  def swim(self):
    print("moving in water.")

nemo = Fish()

nemo.swim()
nemo.breathe()
print(nemo.num_eyes)

cat = Animal()
print(nemo.b)                  # does not depend on line 2 or 5, but depends on 16
```

[image: Код и описание на английском]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. А откуда по-вашему у объекта `nemo` класса `Fish` возьмётся поле `b`, если оно присваивается только в методе `breathe` родительского класса `Animal`, который и вызывается в 16 строке `super().breathe()`? Нет вызова этого метода -> нет поля `nemo.b` -> ошибка.
2. Во второй строке задаётся переменная класса, в 5 переменная экземпляра класса. В вашем сценарии использования разницы нет. При создании экземпляра класса экземпляр получает те же поля, что и класс. Но если вы дальше работаете именно с полем экземпляра класса, то лучше его и задавать в `__init__`, так просто понятнее для тех, кто будет читать код.

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающе! Со вторым вопросом пока ещё буду разбираться, изучать, эксперементировать. А вот по поводу первого вопроса, уже не раз сталкиваюсь со своей невнимательностью в плане чтения кода, и логической последовательности, причем того, что пишу сам.